# Implement Settings in Titanium based iOS app

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, appsettings

I'm currently working on a Titanium based iOS application.

I want to display the application settings in settings app.

[image: Settings]

In iOS we can easily do it using info.plist.

Is there anyway to do this in Titanium ?

I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution.

Please help me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look in the kitchen Sink example, it shows how to do this

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/50131/gettings-app-properties-into-iphone-settings-app